# httpd process status systemctl output

Tags: apache-httpd, cgroups

Can some explain the last portion of this output ( The line starting with `CGROUP` and all the following lines):

````
  systemctl status httpd -l
  httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor     preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-05-20 04:30:57 CEST; 4 weeks 0 days ago
  Docs: man:httpd(8)
    apachectl(8)
  Process: 11758 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 6012 (httpd)
Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
Memory: 2.0M
CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
       ├─ 6012 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─11760 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─11761 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─11762 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─11763 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       └─11764 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

   ```
````

Answer (score 1):

In short, some services spawn a lot of processes. With `System V` init system is not always possible to assign a process to the service that spawned it. Also service may not terminate correctly leaving some children alive.
With `systemd` this problem is solved by placing each service in its own `cgroup`. `Cgroups` are used to corral and manage processes and are a `kernel` feature that allows aggregating processes and all their children into hierarchical organized groups.
To list all processes belonging to a service, use the command `systemd-cgls`. The result is the same for given process if you run `systemctl status service`
More info you can find [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt).